# TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.1

The form on the view looks like:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/episode', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true']) !!}
{!! Form::label('Episode Name') !!}
{!! Form::text('name', null) !!}
{!! Form::label('Description') !!}
{!! Form::text('description', null) !!}
{!! Form::label('Channel') !!}
{!! Form::select('channel', $channels) !!}
{!! Form::label('image') !!}
{!! Form::file('image', ['accept' => 'image/*', 'id' => 'image']) !!}
{!! Form::label('audio', 'Upload Audio file') !!}
{!! Form::file('audio', ['accept' => 'audio/*', 'id' => 'audio']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('SUBMIT') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my controller, I have two methods to handle the uploads of each of the media files, one for the image and the other for the audio file:

```
public function getImageFileUrl()
{
    $filename = Input::file('image');
    Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
    $imgUrl = Cloudder::getResult()['url'];

    return $imgUrl;
}
```

and

```
public function getAudioFileUrl()
{
    $filename = Input::file('audio');
    Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
    $audioUrl = Cloudder::getResult()['url'];

    return $audioUrl;
}
```

Then the create method in my controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $image = $this->getImageFileUrl();
    $audio = $this->getAudioFileUrl();

    Episode::create([
        'episode_name'         => $request->name,
        'episode_description'  => $request->description,
        'image'                => $image,
        'audio_mp3'            => $audio,
        'view_count'           => 0,
        'channel_id'           => $request->channel
    ]);
}
```

The trouble is, when I try to create a new Episode from the view, I get `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`

I thought it is because I have two `file uploaders` in the same form?

What is the workaround for this? I need both uploaders in the same form. I am open to best way to go about this.

Thanks.

Comment: didn't you post this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/33829928/

Comment: If you have further code to add to your other question, please do. This is considered as a repost and your question could get closed as an exact duplicate because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `{!! Form::open() !!}` to open your forms? If you aren't, you need to include the CSRF token by using the helper `csrf_field()`.

For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('episode.create') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

If you are using `{!! Form::open() !!}`, please include your entire form code, it would help to debug your issue.

> I realized that it is because i have two file uploaders in the same form.

This wouldn't cause your issue, you can have as many file fields as you please in a form.

Comment: {!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/episode', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => 'true']) !!}
{!! Form::label('Episode Name') !!}
{!! Form::text('name', null) !!}
{!! Form::label('Description') !!}
{!! Form::text('description', null) !!}
{!! Form::label('Channel') !!}
{!! Form::select('channel', $channels) !!}
{!! Form::label('image') !!}
{!! Form::file('image', ['accept' => 'image/*', 'id' => 'image']) !!}
{!! Form::label('audio', 'Upload Audio file') !!}
{!! Form::file('audio', ['accept' => 'audio/*', 'id' => 'audio']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('SUBMIT') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}